# Resolving abstract class' dependencies via dependency injection in Laravel

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel-5, abstract-class

I encountered this issue using the repository pattern. Currently I use an interface, and a custom class to achieve it, then type-hint it into the controller's construct and because of Laravel, it will solve the repositories' dependencies automatically and recursively.

I also do this in a service provider:

```
$this->app->bind(path/to/repoInterface,path/to/implementationClass)
```

However, because of the way I coded these repositories, in order to avoid code duplication, I created an abstract class that has a common method to all these repositories. This class is as follows:

```
abstract class CommonRepo{

   public function __construct(SomeModelClass model){}

   public function commonMethod(){//Code here}
```

And my repositories have the following structure:

```
public class ExampleRepository extends CommonRepo implements ExampleRepositoryI{

   public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
   }
}
```

Laravel doesn't like this, so its giving this error:

```
Argument 1 passed to path/to/repo/CommonRepo::__construct() must be an instance of path/to/model/SomeModelClass, none given, called in...
```

So, obviously is not resolving the dependency of the class CommonRepo, but it does resolve the dependencies on the normal repositories.

I'd like, if it's possible, to use type-hinting (the Laravel way) without having to do anything related to the *new* operator

How can I, then, resolve that class's dependencies ?
PD: Using Laravel 5.2

Comment: You can get inspired by this http://meanderingsoul.com/dev/2015/04/dependency-injection-with-inherited-controllers-in-laravel-5

Comment: Or maybe just remove constructor from ExampleRepository class if there is nothing more to be done other than calling parent constructor.

Comment: @MateuszDrost I didn't type it, but there is more to do. Each repository has its own dependencies (which often are just Eloquent Models, because I don't like abusing facades).

Answer (score 3):

Parent constructor is called like normal function without touching dependency resolver so you should do one of two possibilities:

```
public class ExampleRepository extends CommonRepo implements ExampleRepositoryI
{    
    public function __construct(SomeModelClass $model){
        parent::__construct($model);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class ExampleRepository extends CommonRepo implements ExampleRepositoryI
{    
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(App::make(SomeModelClass::class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but that's precisely what I want to avoid, because I'd have to write parent::__construct(App::make(SomeModelClass::class)); in every repository (currently I have 6 that extend from that common parent), so if I had to add/delete/modifiy a dependency in that ComonRepo, it's going to get nasty.

Answer (score 2):

nice question. I did some tinkering, though I don't know if this is what you're looking for. But you can dynamically create an instance of Eloquent model required by your repository class.

Let's say you have your `User` model class stored in `app\Models\User.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    //
}
```

You then create a base abstract class for all of your repository classes: `app\Repositories\BaseRepository.php`. This is where you place all common functionalities for your repository classes. But rather than injecting the Eloquent instance through the constructor, you may add a method named `getModel()` to dynamically create an instance of Eloquent model for your repository.

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use ReflectionClass;
use RuntimeException;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

abstract class BaseRepository
{
    protected $modelNamespace = 'App\\Models\\';

    public function getById($id)
    {
        return $this->getModel()->find($id);
    }

    public function getModel()
    {
        $repositoryClassName = (new ReflectionClass($this))->getShortName();

        $modelRepositoryClassName = $this->modelNamespace . Str::replaceLast('Repository', '', $repositoryClassName);

        if (! class_exists($modelRepositoryClassName)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Class {$modelRepositoryClassName} does not exists.");
        }

        return new $modelRepositoryClassName;
    }
}
```

Now let's say you want to create a repository for your `User` model, and this user's repository must implement the following interface: `app\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

interface UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function getByEmail($email);
}
```

You create `app\Repositories\UserRepository.php` class and simply extend it from the `BaseRepository` class. Also don't forget to implement all specific implementations defined on `UserRepositoryInterface`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Repositories\BaseRepository;
use App\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface;

class UserRepository extends BaseRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function getByEmail($email)
    {
        return $this->getModel()->where('email', $email)->firstOrFail();
    }
}
```

This way you can bind the `UserRepositoryInterface` to it's implementation like so:

```
$this->app->bind(\App\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface::class, \App\Repositories\UserRepository::class);
```

Finally you can freely inject the `UserRepositoryInterface` to a controller's constructor or methods. You can also resolve it via service container like this:

```
$userRepository = App::make(App\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface::class);

$userRepository->getByEmail('john@example.com');
```

Of course there's a catch to this approach. The repository class should be started with the associated model, so the `InvoiceRepository.php` is dedicated for `Invoice.php` model class.

Hope this help!

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your response. Even though it is not exactly what I wanted, I can definitely find a use to this in the future, because I constantly find myself injecting the model and sometimes it matches the name of the repo, so it's nice. 
Shouldn't you cache the getModel() method though? like calling it in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

This might help. You can listen in for when an object resolves and set attributes.

```
$this->app->resolving(CommonRepo::class, function ($object, $app) {
    // Called when container resolves object of any type...
    $object->commonObject = app(CommonObject::class);
});
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#container-events